# MySQL alter table generating "error on rename"

Tags: mysql, key, alter

Here's a print of my error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Price DROP FOREIGN KEY Id
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of '.\testdb\Price' to '.\t
estdb\#sql2-bcc-16' (errno: 152)
```

I've read [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table-problems.html)  which suggests that the problem may be due to a left-over table from some earlier alter table error, and recommends you snoop around in your data directory and delete any table with a name such as 'B-xxx.frm'.

My error is similar to this, but there is no '#sql2-bcc-16' in my data directory. And there wouldn't be any artifacts of a previous failed alter table, anyway, because this is just a small test database and I haven't actually altered any tables previously.

EDIT: More info below.

What I really want to do is change an Id (primary key) in another table to be a SMALLINT (instead of a TINYINT). However, THIS Phone table's Id is a foreign key, referencing Id in the other table. So, I believe I need to drop the foreign key of this table before proceeding with the type-change in the primary table. I hope this is clear.

EDIT 2: Tables.

Sale - has Id TINYINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id)

Phone - has Id TINYINT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Sale (Id)

I would like all Ids in my database to be SMALLINT and not TINYINT. That's my current situation.

Comment: The top of my post keeps disappearing. It says "Hi all,..." Someone named 'thinksteep' keeps editing my post.

Comment: I believe Id is primary key in another table... right?

Comment: Fahim - correct! I'll update OP with more relevant information.

Comment: more clearer now.. thanks for edit...

Answer (score 1):

try with `mysql> ALTER TABLE Price DROP Id`

Hope it works... Good Luck

I tried with you query `mysql> ALTER TABLE Price DROP FOREIGN KEY Id`

It executes, but didn't worked!!!

**Update:**

Use below queries...

`mysql> ALTER TABLE Price MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

`mysql> ALTER TABLE Sale MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

`mysql> ALTER TABLE Phone MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

Comment: I still want Phone to have an Id field, I just need to temporarily drop the fact that Id is a foreign key. If I drop the whole column, there would be no way to "re-attach" the Ids after altering the primary table, correct?

Comment: yes... 

my next question : why you want to temporarily drop then?? what exactly you want to do?? Please edit your question

Comment: Also above query will delete Id column from Price table... I believe Phone is another table where Id is primary key...

Can you provide structure of both tables?

Comment: I did edit my question but I'll explain it again here. I have another table, "Sale", with an "Id TINYINT NOT NULL" (and Id is the primary key). I simply want to make Id a SMALLINT and not a TINYINT, but my internet research has led me to believe that this is not possible if there are any foreign keys pointing to this Id. So, I have to drop those keys, first.