# MySQL alter table - changing a TINYINT to a SMALLINT

Tags: mysql, key, alter, sql-types

I have the following database with two tables (excuse my ugly format):

```
TABLE_A : Id TINYINT, PRIMARY KEY (Id)
TABLE_B : Id TINYINT, FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES TABLE_A (Id)
```

I would like to modify Id so that it's a SMALLINT rather than a TINYINT. Here are a couple failed attempts:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE TABLE_A MODIFY Id SMALLINT
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of '.\testdb\#sql-bcc_16' to '.\testdb\table_a' (errno: 150)

mysql> ALTER TABLE TABLE_B DROP FOREIGN KEY (Id)
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of '.\testdb\table_b' to '.\testdb\#sql2-bcc-16' (errno: 152)
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Post what `show create table table_b` shows.

Comment: You should first `ALTER TABLE TABLE_B DROP FOREIGN KEY Id` (where `id` is the name of the Foreign Key).

Comment: solved or still facing error??

Answer (score 3):

Use below queries

`mysql> ALTER TABLE Price MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

`mysql> ALTER TABLE Sale MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

`mysql> ALTER TABLE Phone MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

I also answered it at 
[MySQL alter table generating "error on rename"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905856/mysql-alter-table-generating-error-on-rename) long time back... but you are not replying there...

Here in your case it will be

`mysql> ALTER TABLE TABLE_A MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

`mysql> ALTER TABLE TABLE_B MODIFY Id SMALLINT`

**Update**

check [Help with: ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of .... (errno: 150)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948704/help-with-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-errno-150).. Might help you..

Comment: Fahim - Take a look at my "failed attempts" and error messages. They're the exact same queries you're telling me to run. Thanks for the input, though. :)

Comment: do you already have data in both tables?? I think there is problem of size... How long can TINYINT and SMALLINT hold values?

Comment: can you execute `describe MYTABLE01`, `describe MYTABLE02` and let me know what it gives